# How to block an dll injection via Minifilter

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, kmdf, minifilter

Im trying to `block .dll` injection (or general injection) into a specific process via a [Minifilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/file-system-minifilter-drivers)

This is my PreOperationCallback:

```
    if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_ACQUIRE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION) {
        /* Open file for writing/appending? */
        if ((Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.SecurityContext->DesiredAccess & PAGE_EXECUTE) == PAGE_EXECUTE) {
            if (security) {
                DbgPrint("[ miniFilter ] [IRP_MJ_ACQUIRE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION] [ Blocked ]\n");
                Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
                return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
            }
        }
        if ((Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.SecurityContext->DesiredAccess & FILE_EXECUTE) == FILE_EXECUTE) {
            if (security) {
                DbgPrint("[ miniFilter ] [IRP_MJ_ACQUIRE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION] [ Blocked ]\n");
                Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
                return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to other Forums `IRP_MJ_ACQUIRE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION` will be called on DLL Injection!
I have also tried "IRP_MJ_CREATE" but then I am also blocking any execution of `.exe` files. Filtering the file extension could be easily bypassed...

I hope somebody knows more about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Minifilter is not suitable for this.

**AcquireForSectionSync** is called when a process calls **CreateFileMapping**/**ZwCreateSection**.

Suppose *ProcessA* wants to inject a DLL into *ProcessB*. It can create a remote thread that will make *ProcessB* call **LoadLibrary**.

At that point your filter will see that *ProcessB* calls **AcquireForSection** sync which every process does when it starts up as the loader will load all the basic dlls like: `ntdll`, `kernel32`, etc...

What you want is Ob callbacks, e.g.:

> [ObRegisterCallbacks function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-obregistercallbacks)
>
> ---
>
> The **ObRegisterCallbacks** routine registers a list of callback routines for thread, process, and desktop handle operations.

These callback will allow you to prevent a process from opening another process with various rights.

Imagine you have a scenario where *ProcessA* wants to inject something into *ProcessB* via some sort of **CreateRemoteThread**/**ReadWriteProcessMemory** manipulation.

**ProcessA**:

```
OpenProcess(ProcessB, PROCESS_VM_...);

YouDriverObCallbackRoutine() {
   Check if ProcessA should have access it asks for ProcessB.
   If not you can simply strip away the access and return.
}
```

This will result in *ProcessA* having a handle without those rights to *ProcessB*.

Now when *ProcessA* tries to call

- **CreateRemoteThread**
- **ReadProcessMemory**
- **WriteProcessMemory**

on *ProcessB*, the system will deny the access as the handle does not have those rights anymore (you stripped them in your Ob callback).

Comment: ObCallBacks are not enough. For example, SetWindowsHookEx() will completely ignore the callbacks.